# Selenium Firefox stuck after downloading a file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver

I am using python selenium (last version) with geckodriver 0.31.0 and Firefox 103 to login a website and download a file, but after downloading the file, browser is stuck and `browser.quit()` is never invoked.

This is the relevant code:

```
s = Service(DRIVER_PATH)

firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2) # to not use the default directory for downloading the file
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False) # turns off the showing of download progress
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/home/<myuser>/")
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.directory_upgrade", True)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.prompt_for_download", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
firefox_options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", True)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=firefox_options)

browser.get(URL)

browser.find_element(By.NAME, "login").send_keys(USER)
browser.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(PASSWORD)
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, CLASS).click()

# download file
browser.get(URL + "feed.rss")

time.sleep(3)

browser.quit()
```

I know I can download the file with python `requests` by passing selenium cookies but I need to download the file with Selenium.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 102.3 shows the download window with this profile (at least in java). I needed to add the following config line:

"browser.download.alwaysOpenPanel" = false

I am not sure if this helps with python or if this is the problem. In selenium-java, I loose the focus with certain code if there is a popup window ("Show all downloads").

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Python and this doesn't solve my problem (Firefox 106.0.3).